# Nestjs Image Validation

Tags: image, upload, nestjs

I have created an endpoint to upload an avatar and the controller is like this :

```
  @Post('/avatar')
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileInterceptor('file', {
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: './public/avatars',
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
          const { user } = req as unknown as { user: typeof ReqUser };
          const { id } = user as unknown as { id: string };

          const filename: string = id;
          const extension: string = path.parse(file.originalname).ext;
          cb(null, `${filename}${extension}`);
        },
      }),
    }),
  )
  async uploadAvatar(
    @UploadedFile(
      new ParseFilePipe({
        validators: [
          new MaxFileSizeValidator({ maxSize: 5000000 }),
          new FileTypeValidator({ fileType: /image\/(jpeg|png|jpg)/ }),
        ],
      }),
    )
    file: Express.Multer.File,
    @ReqUser() user,
  ) {
    return this.meService.setAvatar(file, user);
  }
```

The problem Im facing is that if the file isnt valid, the corresponding error will be thrown but the file will be uploaded on the server, for example it should only allow image upload with .jpg,png,jpg extention, but the file will be be uploaded anyway? what am i doing wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @jaymcdoniel explained, the interceptor will run before the code executes your `uploadAvatar` function.

To stop uploading the file to your server's storage, you could use [`fileFilter` option in Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#filefilter).

```js
@Post('/avatar')
@UseInterceptors(
  FileInterceptor('file', {
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
      // Write your condition below based on the mimetype and/or filename extension.
      if (<YOUR_CONDITION_TO_REJECT_THE_FILE>) {
        cb(null, false);
      } else {
        cb(null, true);
      }
    },
    storage: diskStorage({
      destination: './public/avatars',
      filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const { user } = req as unknown as { user: typeof ReqUser };
        const { id } = user as unknown as { id: string };

        const filename: string = id;
        const extension: string = path.parse(file.originalname).ext;
        cb(null, `${filename}${extension}`);
      },
    }),
  })
)
async uploadAvatar(
  ...
```

This will prevent Multer from saving the file inside your sever at first. This way, you will not need to handle deleting the file incase the file is of wrong type.

Comment: I followed your instructions and indeed it works, but it seems that somehow I have a bug? because I can't access size of the file from the req, inside fileFilter.

Comment: Happy to be of help. `file` parameter should ideally have all the properties mentioned under [File Information](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information). When you say you cannot access, what do you mean? Does `file.size` return `undefined`?

Comment: exactly, it returns as undefined, even tho the file inside it shows that it has the size.
[link](https://imgur.com/BDP7pFJ)

Comment: Looks like they [don't have `size` property for `file` inside the `filteFilter` function](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/186). What you see is the properties of the type which ideally should have been modified to show only the available properties (That is an issue on their types). Anyway, you can use `limits` property instead if you want to [limit the file size](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#limits).

Answer (score 0):

The interceptor goes through, in its entirety, before the `ParseFilePipe` has a chance to run its validations. You could catch the error in an exception filter, pull the `req.file` and get the file path, and then delete the file on exception. Otherwise, you can load the file into memory, and save it using the `fs` module only after validation has passed